# transparent element click event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Hei,
I have this html code:

```
<div class="overlay_swf" onclick="closeSwf()"></div>
<div onclick="location.href='http://google.com'" class="centered clickable"></div>
<div class="theSwf centered">
    <object id="flash" style="width: 1055px; height: 510px;" name="Web" data="http://some_swf_file.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="movie" value="http://some_swf_file.swf">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" border="0" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"> </a>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
</div>
```

Now I need to implement the onClick event in the .centered.clickable (transparent) div...
It works good in Chrome and IE, But in firefox its not working.
BUT When I Change the transparent background to red for example...its working good.

How can I fix it to wirk on firefox with the transparent div?
thanks

Comment: Can you share your CSS code or jsfiddle here?

Comment: A JSfiddle would be nice :)

Comment: You can try put any color to the .centered.clickable div but put a 0 opacity. Probably not the best solution though.